# How to connect remote machine using CLI

Tags: windows, command-line, remote, gui, teamviewer

I want to connect one of my Windows/Linux machines remotely via CLI(command-line interface).
I can login into the remote machine with team viewer(GUI).
Is there any software that help me to create a remote session from backend over the internet?
Please let me know if it is possible.
Thankyou

Comment: Did you Google this?  I have no doubt that you will get a ton of hits if you do!

Comment: I just created a thread for discussion. So, that i could get some recommended tool that already been used by someone as well as get feedback on that. Please do share, if you have any!

Comment: Super User is not a forum, but a Q&A site. It's not about discussions but about getting answers. Your question can be easily answered by googling.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, starting a quick [reverse SSH](https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) tunnel is likely your best bet.

In Windows you're likely best off doing something third party, as even if you start telnet and route it properly, you're using telnet over the Internet which is security hell in just about any situation.

I don't know of any native functionality for teamviewer to make it accept command line connections. Accessing a computer silently (through CLI) through teamviewer IMHO would be a security mess and would make teamviewer spywareish.

***You probably should've googled this instead of posting it here, for future reference.***